# Por que meus imports estão dando erro?

Tags: android, android-studio

Passados alguns dias que abri o projeto, hoje voltei ao trabalho porém quando abri o projeto notei que havia algo errado pois todas as classes que eu abro indicam erro pela **IDE**, erros como por exemplo:

> cannot resolve symbol 'Activity', cannot resolve symbol 'Intent'

Ou seja, qualquer *import* a **IDE** já mostra erro, eu dei um *clean* no projeto, já voltei até um backup do projeto e de nada adiantou. Alguém já passou por isto?

Estou na versão **1.5.1** e o Java que tenho é a versão **7** 
`D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`.

O *SDK* do Android está todo atualizado.

Comment: quando você abre o seu android studio ele não te retorna nenhum erro no gradle? ja aconteceu algo parecido aqui e era uma configuração do gradle, mas o android studio me retornava que o problema era la.

Comment: tente atualizar a versão do gradle, no arquivo **build.gradle** do projeto  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.21' ..

Answer (score 0):

Comigo aconteceu isso, eu resolvi dessa forma:
menu -> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...
botão -> Invalidade and Restart